# Change highlight colour for textfield in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, uitextfield, textfield, flutter-web

Is there any way to change the colour of a Textfield's highlight in Flutter? [image: So this is without highlighting]

So when I highlight it does not look like this:
[image: highlighted]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1.** You can change the `textSelectionColor` in the `theme` of your app:

```
theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
  textSelectionColor: Colors.black
),
```

**Solution 2.** You can change the `textSelectionColor` only for a specific `TextField` by wrapping it with a `Theme` widget:

```
Theme(
  data: ThemeData(
    textSelectionColor: Colors.black,
  ),
  child: TextField(
  ),
),
```